# Custom CheckBox in TableView

Tags: java, javafx, cell, factory

I want to apply a custom style using the `setStyle` method to the `CheckBox` of a TableView but I can not do it. I have tried to create a CheckBox inside the `setCellFactory` regardless of `CheckBoxTableCell` but in that case the value in the `ObservableList<Person>` is no longer updated.

My code is the following:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private boolean accepted;

    public Person(String name, boolean accepted) {
        this.name = name;    
        this.accepted = accepted;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public boolean isAccepted() {
        return accepted;
    }
    public void setAccepted(boolean accepted) {
        this.accepted = accepted;
    }
}
```

The main class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableViewWithCheckBox extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();

        // Editable
        table.setEditable(true);
        TableColumn<Person, String> fullNameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        TableColumn<Person, Boolean> acceptedCol = new TableColumn<>("Accepted");

        // NAME
        fullNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        fullNameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Person> forTableColumn());
        fullNameCol.setMinWidth(200);

        // ACCEPTED
        acceptedCol.setCellValueFactory((CellDataFeatures<Person, Boolean> param) -> {
            Person person = param.getValue();           
            SimpleBooleanProperty booleanProp = new SimpleBooleanProperty(person.isAccepted());

            booleanProp.addListener(
                    (ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
                            Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
                        person.setAccepted(newValue);
                    });
            return booleanProp;
        });

        acceptedCol.setCellFactory((TableColumn<Person, Boolean> p) -> {
            CheckBoxTableCell<Person, Boolean> cell = new CheckBoxTableCell<>();
            cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            return cell;
        });

        ObservableList<Person> list = getPersonList();
        table.setItems(list); 
        table.getColumns().addAll(fullNameCol, acceptedCol);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        root.getChildren().add(table);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private ObservableList<Person> getPersonList() { 
        Person person1 = new Person("John White", true);
        Person person2 = new Person("Kevin Land", false);
        Person person3 = new Person("Rouse Hill", true); 
        ObservableList<Person> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(person1, person2, person3);
        return list;
    }
}
```

And the code with a custom `CheckBox` but that does not update the observable list:

```
    acceptedCol.setCellFactory((TableColumn<Person, Boolean> success) -> {
        TableCell<Person, Boolean> cell = new TableCell<Person, Boolean>(){                
            @Override
            public void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if(empty || item == null){
                    setGraphic(null);   
                } else {
                    CheckBox myCheckBox = new CheckBox();
                    myCheckBox.getStyleClass().add("myPersonalCheckBoxStyle");
                    myCheckBox.setSelected(item);
                    setGraphic(myCheckBox);                      
                }
            }
        };         
        return cell;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CheckBoxTableCell does all the heavy lifting for you, just need a little help from your Person class which should use/expose properties (vs. plain fields with getters/setters only). Then configure the column with the acceptedProperty and apply a custom style to the cell.

In code snippets:

```
public class Person {

    private BooleanProperty accepted;

    public Person(String name, boolean single) {
        this.accepted = new SimpleBooleanProperty(single);
        ... 
    }

    public BooleanProperty acceptedProperty() {
        return accepted;
    }

    public boolean isAccepted() {
        return acceptedProperty().get();
    }

    ....
```

Configuration of the column with cell/Value/Factory:

```
acceptedCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("accepted"));

acceptedCol.setCellFactory((TableColumn<Person, Boolean> p) -> {
    CheckBoxTableCell<Person, Boolean> cell = new CheckBoxTableCell<>();
    cell.getStyleClass().add("custom-cell");
    cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    return cell;
});
```

Some custom style:

```
/**
 * Just want to see an effect, doesn't matter what
 */
.custom-cell > .check-box {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
}
.custom-cell > .check-box:selected {
    -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I have entered the changes that you suggest but the checkboxes do not show the values of the observable list and I can not activate them with the mouse.

Comment: hmm ... works for me - you sure removed all your custom wiring? Please show the complete program after the change. BTW, which version of fx do you have (mine is fx9.0.1)